# Anyone else seen standard Yes/No togglers fail to render in the Advanced Custom Fields Pro wordpress plugin?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I've never seen this one. Standard togglers, which can be seen on all field group pages, as well as UX on types like button groups, are failing to render the toggle box on load. Instead it just prints YesNo. The togglers still work, just you can't tell that they are doing anything.

There are no JS errors. No PHP errors. And I have disabled all plugins, and switched the theme back to the standard 20xx theme. I even deleted ACF Pro and copied a different one from another project that is working fine. Nothing changes. I still see the field rendered like the attached image. Beneath it is what it's supposed to look like.

Anyone else seen this or have ideas on what could be going on here?

[image: What I am getting]

[image: What I should be getting]

I have suspicions maybe a left over setting or something in the database confusing things, or like a hook defined somewhere that is interfering. But I am unaware of any such hook that would interfere with something like this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because https://wordpress.stackexchange.com is a better place to find people who know this kind of stuff.

Comment: I don't know, I figured since there's 180,000 wordpress questions here, and 4,000 ACF questions it might be logical to ask here. I usually get better and faster responses on the main stackoverflow site than any of the subsets.